# "It has to install from unauthenticated sources" from software updater

Tags: update-manager

I tried updating my 13.04 from software updater. I had about 202.9 MB to download. When I click "Install Now" and then a message came saying "It has to install from unauthenticated sources". I click OK and then the software updater Exits... There is no way I can update due to this problem.

[image: Install Now]
[image: Error Popped]

Comment: what does sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade prints on terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that somehow you messed up your keyrings or your DNS got hi-hacked. I will ask you to execute one by one these commands and stop when you see an error:

1. Clean your `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo rename 's/\.list$/\.list\.disable/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archives.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-security main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archives.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-updates main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
   ```
2. Update your list (be sure that you have rebooted)

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-keyring
   ```
3. Now update as normal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

If you have another instance of apt-get please close it, be it Ubuntu Software Center, apt-get, synaptic, aptitude, gdebi, etc.

Comment: I have taken your advise and slavishly executed the command lines. The updater showed again but, since then it relentlessly says "All packages are up to date" which I do not believe (I did it last week). What to do ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. in stable, packages rarely have updates.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **Software Sources** list and eliminate them one by one to identify the source of your problem.

You may also run `sudo apt-get -f install` in terminal to try fixing things for you (it wouldn't harm your system running it anyway) and follow it with `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Also, perhaps editing your question with a print screen or error details would bring you better help :)

---

Update:

1. I prefer re-checking your software source list as there should be a
   source that is causing the issue.
2. Please execute the previous commands (`-f install`, then `update`, then
   `upgrade`).
3. If issue persists, run this to override (***which I don't recommend
   unless you know exactly what you are doing***):

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated
   ```

Comment: [The Screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/Dg67W)

Comment: I have given above the screen shots of the errors

Comment: Sorry it said "Unauthenticated Sources" Not "untrusted sources..

Comment: No problem, updates in the post for better formating

Comment: Oh GOD.. I did sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated and this came up..Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Comment: Reboot then run again (run them one by one this time, the && is the separator between the two commands) or wait a while till current operation complets (you may use **System Monitor** to know if there is any download or installation is in progress)....... however, I think this is a good sign.

Comment: Ok that got lock error go away and runnning commands as abouve..

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand :( would you explain a little more :) Do you mean that there is no more errors and update is in progress now?

Comment: Nope.... THe "not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) –d is no more troubling me

Comment: Why not recommending to override? What `--allow-unauthenticated` do is just [**ignore** if packages can't be authenticated](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-get.8.html) and don't prompt about it. This is useful for tools like pbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Open System settings, and click on Software & Updates.  Once the window opens, click on the Authentication tab, and then click on Restore Defaults.  close the window, and try the Software manager again.

[image]

Comment: Nope..still didnt work...after i click intall, i am getting " You have to install from unauthenticated sources" And whne i click Insatll, The window just closes...

Answer (score -2):

Try typing `sudo do-release-upgrade` as an administrator into a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and put the error here.

Comment: I did and it says "No new release found"

Comment: That means that Ubuntu thinks, maybe incorrectly that it's on the latest release, 13.04.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser he is just doing and Update not upgrade (already using 13.04) so **do-release-upgrade** won't do anything unless using -d switch for a development release

Comment: And he is already having the latest release :)